# Can a cubic polynomial can have two different double roots?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm taking a calculus class and we're supposed to answer true or false questions, but I don't even know what a double root in a cubic polynomial is.

Comment: A double root corresponds to a repeated linear factor. For example, $x^3-2x^2 + x$ has a double root at $1$ because it is factored as $x(x-1)^2$.

Comment: Two different double roots would mean 4 roots, and a cubic has only three roots. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

A double root is a root of the same value that occurs twice. For a quadratic this would imply
$$
(x-a)^2=0
$$
Two different double roots implies, with $a \neq  b$
$$
(x-a)^2(x-b)^2=0
$$
If you expand this, do you get a cubic polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. In elementary terms, if a cubic equation $f(x)$ were to have two distinct double roots, $u$ and $v$, then we could write it as

$$f(x) = a (x - u)^2 (x- v)^2$$
where $a \neq 0$ (as then $f$ is not cubic and is the zero function). But we can already see that there is a nonzero coefficient on the fourth-order term, which is $ax^4$, so this is a contradiction of $f$ being cubic..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. A double root is an $x$-value where the curve not only crosses the $x$-axis, but the curve is also tangent to that axis (think of the way $y=x^2$ touches the $x-axis at the origin). There are two key facts here:

1.) A polynomial of degree $d$ can only have at most $d$ roots.

2.) A double root counts as two roots in this calculation.

Since having two double roots is like counting 4 roots, and for a cubic polynomial $d=3$, this is impossible.